# Is there a framework agnostic captcha module for Python?

Tags: python, captcha

I want to add captcha support to some forms, I'm using a very lightweight Python framework, `bottle`, and I don't want to use something provided by an online service, like recaptcha.

Is there something already available in this direction, or is messing around with PIL the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SkimpyGimpy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/skimpyGimpy), it's a python package that let's you generate CAPTCHA images and audio files. This is the package most framework-specific captcha generators that do not use re-captcha rely on.

It's a bit primitive, you may want to look at the source of [collective.captcha](http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser/collective.captcha/trunk/collective/captcha/browser/captcha.py) as an example of how to use SkimpyGimpy in your own code.

*Obligatory disclaimer: I am the original author of the collective.captcha package. Your mileage may vary. Don't code and drive, especially based on the say-so from others.*

Answer (score 1):

Found a couple: http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=captcha&submit=search

Pick one, cut the version number and use *one* of these commands (for example):

```
easy_install collective.captcha
pip install collective.captcha
```

Comment: But this would depend on Plone. Isn't this a BIG dependency?

Comment: No, it only depends on plone.keyring (which has some transitive dependencies). plone.* packages are made by the Plone community but do not require Plone itself to run.

That said, plone.keyring does need the ZODB persistent object database to store the server-side secret and *that* may be too heavy a dependency for a bottle-based application.